# Что есть для форматирования кода в lua?

Tags: lua, поиск-программ

Есть ли что-то подобное `clang-format` для форматирования кода, написанного на `lua`?

Comment: Одиночество в сети. Никто не пользуется lua в Местной Группе Галактик. :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 я их понимаю)

Comment: А что, сильно кривое поделие?

Comment: lua нужна для микроскриптов, которые можно засунуть в роутер или контроллер. большие проекты на нем не пишут. а так классный язык, @pepsicoca1

Comment: @eri это понятно, но это не означает, что код должен быть отфарматирован. К примеру на проекту 2 человека, в проекту есть участок кода на `lua` который был отредактирован в двух ветках, где, в обоих случаях была добавлена функция `tmp`. При этом один прогер использует пробел между именем функции, а другой нет. Как результат: конфликт при мержинге. Да, такие ситации не часты, но, все же, я привык полагаться на автоматическое форматирование кода и не сталкиваться с такими вот конфликтами вообще.

Comment: я вот товарища от табов отучить не могу)

Comment: @eri вот-вот, а с автоформатированием этой проблемы просто не возникнет!

Comment: Если есть такие проблемы, и на рынке нет достойного продукта, то может стоит самим написать форматер для lua? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел хороший форматтер для `lua` а-ля `clang-format`: настройка с помощью файла, работает с потоками ввода вывада и т.д. Если кому будет полезно: [lua-format](https://github.com/Koihik/LuaFormatter)